# Detect that code is running as a Chrome extension, from a remote site, within iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Question: is it possible to detect if js code running on a remote site is being called from within an iframe in a Chrome extension? I have a remote website where I, when called as a Chrome extension, want to override a couple behaviors, and instead use chrome.runtime.sendMessage and chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal to send a command back to the extension.

In my popup.html i have this:

```
<iframe src="http://localhost" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

In my js on the remote site (localhost for testing), i have this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (someHowCheckIfIAmBeingCalledFromAChromeExtension == true) { //what do I put here?
    {
        // The ID of the extension we want to talk to.
        var extensionId = "abc";

        // Make a simple request:
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionId, { message: "connected!" },
          function (response) {
              if (!response.success)
                  handleError(message);
          });
    }
}
});
```

In my popup.js I have:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
     //do something with request.message
});
```

Is this in any way possible or not? I have looked at many other articles and questions that kinda talk about what I am trying to do, but non set me on the right track exactly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this the following way:

1. Pointed the iframe in popup.html to localhost/index?extension=chrome
2. Added the following jquery to index on the remote/localhost site:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
   //check if query string is present
   if (getParameterByName('extension') == 'chrome')
       {
           var extensionId = "abc";
           //append the query string of each link on the page to make sure the site stays in "extension mode"
       $('a').each(function () {
          var _href = $(this).attr('href');
          var _newHref;
          if (_href.indexOf('?') >= 0) {
             _newHref = _href + '&extension=chrome';
          } else {
              _newHref = _href + '?extension=chrome';
       }
       $(this).attr("href", _newHref);
   });

   //after this line I catch/change/override any behavior I want to change when the site is used form within the extension
   //Then, I use chrome.runtime.sendMessage to send any custom commands to the extension
   }
   });
   ```
3. Then, in popup.js I have to following:

   ```
   chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
       function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
           //do something with the caught behavior
   });

   //If you want to make the website snap out of "extension mode",
   //clean all urls with this function when forwarding urls/opening tabs from the extension.
   //The website will then function as usual, stripped of all the extension specific behaviour.
   function cleanChromeExtensionQueryString(url)
   {
       var cleaned;
       if (url.indexOf('?extension=chrome') >= 0) {
           cleaned = url.replace('?extension=chrome', '');
    }
    else if (url.indexOf('&extension=chrome') >= 0) {
        cleaned = url.replace('&extension=chrome', '');
    };
    return cleaned;
    }
   ```

This method allows me to reuse a responsive web site as a Chrome extension while still being able to modify certain behaviors so they become more "extension-esque" :-).

This overall approach is not suitable for all scenarios of course but it happend to work for my current project. I other cases you'll be better off just creating the extension from scratch.